# How to detect if subscriber has left Redis PUB/SUB channel?

Tags: node.js, redis

I've multiple instances of app running. Every instance has users chatting to each other across instances. I need to show if user has gone offline. That wont happen if instance crashes. While instance is alive I can get an event of connection lost via websocket for that socket and inform other instances. But that won't happen if app instance crashed.

Comment: I think you answered your own question.  If you can't rely on the event in the case of a crash, you need some other mechanism, like a timeout or occasional polling.

Comment: When a subscriber connects with Redis and subscribes to a channel. Redis keeps tracks of what connection is subscribed to what channel(s). I'm sure internally Redis gets notified is connection closes and then it removes that connection as subscriber of all channels it was subscribed to. I just want to access that event when connection is closed.

Comment: Maybe you can clarify what you mean by an instance crashes?

Comment: you run app.js on four different servers. One crashes, or get down scaled due to lack of traffic etc!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CLIENT LIST` to achieve the goal. This command lists the info of all clients connecting to Redis. The following is an example of client info displayed by `CLIENT LIST`:

```
id=87 addr=127.0.0.1:63950 fd=10 name= age=3 idle=3 flags=P db=0 sub=3 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=subscribe
```

1. If the client crashes or closes the connection, Redis will remove it from the client list, and you CANNOT get its **addr** from the result of `CLIENT LIST` command.
2. If the client is subscribing/psubscribing one or more channels/patterns, the **cmd** field of the client info will be *subscribe* or *psubscribe*, and the **sub**/**psub** field is the number of channels/patterns it subscribed.
3. If the client unsubscribes/punsbuscribes all channels/patterns, and is sending other command to Redis, the **cmd** field of the client info will be the last command it sent to Redis, and **sub**/**psub** field will be 0.

In order to find out which subscriber has left, you can periodically call `CLIENT LIST` command and check the info of each connecting clients.